# Displaying lines from a randomly opened text file

Tags: c#

I cant seem to figure out whats wrong. I want to read from a random .txt file when the button 'Next' is pressed, then display the string contained in the array allLines[] at index 3. It only seems to print that index of that file and not randomly select another another file to read from. This is just a small program to help me study, using flash cards. I guess there might be one i could download, but any ideas?

```
namespace MSU_Flash_Cards
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Users\\Public\\cards\\");
    Random rand = new Random ();

    int cardside;
    int filecount;
    int fileindex;
    string[] filename;

    string[] allLines;
    // allLines[0] is for Card Name
    // allLines[1] is for Card Description
    // allLines[2] is for Card Front
    // allLines[3] is for Card Back       

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cardside = 0;
    }
    private void btnNewCardSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = 0;
        //store the text in the text boxes in an array
        string[] s_temp = new String[4];
        s_temp[0] = txtboxNewCardName.Text.ToString();
        s_temp[1] = txtboxNewCardDesc.Text.ToString();
        s_temp[2] = txtboxNewCardFront.Text.ToString();
        s_temp[3] = txtboxNewCardBack.Text.ToString();
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(string.Format("C:\\Users\\Public\\cards\\{0}.txt", s_temp[0])); // s_temp[0] is used here to define the file name to use.

        while (x <= 3)
        {
            //write each segment of the array to a file, lines from 0-3
            sw.WriteLine(s_temp[x].ToString());
            x++;
        }
        sw.Close();
    }
    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        // Randomly get the next card
        SetNextCard();
        // Display the next cards 'back'
        txtboxCard.Text = string.Format("{0}", allLines[3]);
    }
    private void btnFlip_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cardside == 0)
        {
            // if the front is showing, switch to the back
            txtboxCard.Text = string.Format("{0}", allLines[3]);
            cardside = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            // if the back is listed, switch to the front
            txtboxCard.Text = string.Format("{0}", allLines[2]);
            cardside = 0;
        }
    }       
    private void SetNextCard()
    {   
        int x = 0;

        // Check the directory for files & count them
        FileInfo[] rgFiles = di.GetFiles("*.*");
        filecount = di.GetFiles().Length;

        // Create a new array based on the filecount
        filename = new String[filecount];

        // Save each file name in the array
        foreach (FileInfo fi in rgFiles)
        {
            filename[x] = fi.FullName;
            x++;
        }

        // Select randomly a file for reading
        fileindex = rand.Next(0, filecount); 

        // Read each line of the file and assign to a global array for use later
        allLines = File.ReadAllLines(string.Format("{0}", filename));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you trying walking though the code in a debugger?

Comment: i did. the int filecount correctly represents the file quantity in the folder, but filename doesnt change. Maybe im just tired and missing something obvious. Im still pretty new at this though.

Comment: One note: there's no point in using `string.Format` the way you're commonly using it. `txtboxCard.Text = string.Format("{0}", allLines[3]);` could just as simply be written `txtboxCard.Text = allLines[3];`

Comment: You're right. I had that in there because i had it originally formatted with the '\n' newline character and forgot to take it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You set the value of `fileindex`, but never use it. You probably want to change the last line to:

```
allLines = File.ReadAllLines(filename[fileindex]);
```

Also, there doesn't seem to be any reason why `fileindex` should be a field and not a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

You're not indexing into your filename array, the index is missing.

```
allLines = File.ReadAllLines(filename[fileindex]);
```

Comment: so something like:
allLines[index number] = File.ReadAllLines(filename[fileindex]);
but then add a foreach statement to add each line found in the file?

Answer (score 0):

You're not indexing into your filename array when you try to read a file, so it can't find the file you want to open. Replace your last line

```
allLines = File.ReadAllLines(string.Format("{0}", filename));
```

with

```
allLines = File.ReadAllLines(filename[fileindex]);
```

to read the selected file.

Comment: He actually is passing a `string` to `ReadAllLines()`, because that's what `string.Format()` returns. But that string doesn't make any sense.